# No module named 'social_django' but 'social-auth-app-django' is installed

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, social-auth-app-django

## Summary of Issue

I am creating a Django project and attempting to setup Auth0 integrations. Per Auth0's documentation, I installed the `social-auth-app-django` library which then went and also installed `social-auth-core`. So please note that **both these libraries are installed**.

Here is my `py -m pip list` output proving such:

```
Package                Version
---------------------- ---------
asgiref                3.4.1
certifi                2021.10.8
cffi                   1.15.0
charset-normalizer     2.0.7
colorama               0.4.4
cryptography           35.0.0
defusedxml             0.7.1
Django                 3.2.9
ecdsa                  0.17.0
idna                   3.3
oauthlib               3.1.1
pip                    21.3.1
pyasn1                 0.4.8
pycparser              2.21
PyJWT                  2.3.0
python-dotenv          0.19.2
python-jose            3.3.0
python-social-auth     0.3.6
python3-openid         3.2.0
pytz                   2021.3
requests               2.26.0
requests-oauthlib      1.3.0
rsa                    4.7.2
setuptools             57.4.0
six                    1.16.0
social-auth-app-django 5.0.0
social-auth-core       4.1.0
sqlparse               0.4.2
urllib3                1.26.7
```

As you can see, I'm running Django 3.2.9. I am also using Python 3.10.

After following all of Auth0's steps, I went to run `py manage.py migrate` and receive the following ending error message:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'social_django'`

## What I have tried

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the `social-auth-app-django` and `social-auth-core` libraries multiple times. I have also tried installing the libraries individually instead of just installing `social-auth-app-django`. I have also tried installing `social-auth-app[django]` (using brackets). Nothing has worked.

Every post I can find online is telling the OP to install the `social-auth-app-django` library and that should fix their problem. But as demonstrated, I believe I've already done that. So unless there's a different way I need to install the library, I need a different solution.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you may have the most common problem - you may have installed two Pythons and you installed module in one Python but you run code with other Python. Pythons don't share modules and you have to install module in correct Python. In code you can run `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python` and then run `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...` to install module in this Python.

Comment: @furas Interesting... when I print sys.executable, it prints out the path to my python 3.8 executable. But I've set everything up using the python 3.10 prefix anytime I run a python command.

Is this disparity coming from a Django Project setting? How can I make the project execute using the Python 3.10 executable?

Comment: Got it! I had created my virtual environment using python 3.8 instead of 3.10. So everything instead of the virtual environment was not installed with the correct version. Thank you @furas for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Huge credit to @furas in the comments helping point me in the right direction.

**The Solution:** Reinitialize the virtual environment using python 3.10 instead of python 3.8 and reinstall necessary packages.

**Explanation:** The problem was that I had inadvertently created my venv using python 3.8. So even though I'd run `py -m pip list` successfully while inside of the 3.8 venv, all of my packages were still installed using python 3.8. So when I'd try and migrate using python 3.10, the packages weren't viewable.